# Run SSH on SSH server using Java

Tags: java, ssh, jsch, tunnel

I want to open `ssh` by terminal with Java, JSch library and Ubuntu operating system, but there is error like this:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

This is my code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

public class Basic {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String host = "dem.web.com";
        String user = "app";
        String password = "web";
        String command1 = "ssh app@web";
        try {

            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "No");
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            com.jcraft.jsch.Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();

            Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command1);
            channel.setInputStream(null);
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

            InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
            channel.connect();
            byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
            while (true) {
                while (in.available() > 0) {
                    int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                    if (i < 0)
                        break;
                    System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                }
                if (channel.isClosed()) {
                    channel=session.openChannel("exec");
                    break;
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception ee) {
                }
            }
            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
            System.out.println("DONE");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Is there someone who can help me? Or is there another way that easier?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to SSH from `dem.web.com` to `web`. But you do not provide any credentials or any other method for authentication. So the authentication naturally fails.

Anyway, running `ssh` is not the best way to automate tunneling. Use [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) instead.

First create a session to `dem.web.com` that forwards a local port (say `2222`) to `web:22`. And then create another session that connects to the `localhost:2222`.

See http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/PortForwardingL.java.html